# user_ID tracking in analytics

Tags: google-analytics, userid

I am trying to implement user_ID tracking in analytics under the ".js" feature.  Can someone help with assigning a "unique, persistent, and non-personally identifiable string ID" to an existing user of my google site.

For the sake of the argument, the existing user has the following fictional email address registered with my google site: frixbee@frixbee.com

I have already checked user_ID related queries but no specific answer

Comment: The time used reaching me via email would have been much better spent in reading [help], in particular the "Improve posts by editing or commenting" part. Your post came up for review as it was triaged by multiple people as needing improvement. I removed the question irrelevant thanks (and should have removed the "Sorry I am no programmer").  I have no ideas about your actual problem, but the changes I made make the question faster to read without question relevant information loss, a plus for all visitors and potential answerers.

Answer (score 1):

User ID is something unique stored on your server/database related to email or phonenumeber or whatever identifying.

You need to have some anonymouse string internally related to real user, but publicly you send only anonymouse string - the User ID.

Some macro in your template or CMS have tu join Javascript Unioversal Analytics configuration snippet:

As Eike Says:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': 'USER_ID' });
```

Where **USER_ID** is macro of your template system returning that anonymouse string.

Comment: Thank you Herr Kreuz, much appreciated.

Comment: Sadly, not being a programmer, I do not know how create that unique string internally on the server. I was wondering if there was an easy way of doing it using 'custom definitions' in analytics, i.e. define a csv with the relationship between the emails in question and the USER_ID strings and upload it onto the google server within analytics as a custom definition. The property is a google site. Would that work? Then i would have to add Eike's tracker to the tracking code. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather unclear what you mean by "the .js feature".

For the user id, you have to generate this serverside and store it along with the user data (you cannot store this on the client side via cookies or the like, since this won't work for users who clear their cookies or visit the site with different devices).

Apart from that it doesn't matter that much which format you use for the userid - this might be the hashed/encrypted email address, or a random number, or the millisecond at which the user registered. The important thing is that is must not be possible to recognize the user from the id (except for yourself by matching it to a stored record on the server).

You pull the id from the server and [pass it to Analytics via Javascript](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id)

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': 'USER_ID' });
```

You need to create a special userid view which will only show data from authenticated users.

Comment: How good of you to help out- thank you!  under the admin section of each property, there is a menu called .js which has several options underneath, one of them which enables activating user_ID etc. this is what i am referring to.

Comment: with regards to your specific answer, what i cannot figure out is exactly where i create that link between the user and the string, which one is the server you refer, and where do i paste that bit of coding. can i paste it directly into the window in property/admin/.js/tracking code ? will this then apply tracking to the whole property?

Comment: to be more specific, would the bit of coding that i need to generate look like this: ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'frixbee@frixbee.com': '194member_01' }); ? if so, where do i establish the link between frixbee@frixbee.com and the unique string 194member_01, please? many thanks again! truly grateful.

Comment: Frankly I don't think this is doable for a non-programmer. The server is the machine that runs your website, and it must run a database with information about the users so they can log in. You would use a programming language to pull data from that database (specifics depend on your server software) and pass it to GA.

Comment: or if the USER_ID needs to be a number, would the coding go: ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': '19401' }); ? in which case where do I establish the link between frixbee@frixbee.com and 19401, please? sorry, my programming knowledge is close to zilch :) thank you.

Comment: so, my property being a google site, it would be performed on the google servers then. but would google give me access to their servers?

Comment: I don't think so. here's a bit of documentation on GA for Google Sites:https://support.google.com/sites/answer/97459?hl=en, but this does not mention the user_id feature.

Comment: thank you Eike, i appreciate it. Clearly i will need a coder to help with this one. Best, Sabin